# Original error packageAndLaunchActivityFrommanifest failed

Tags: android, appium, appium-desktop

an unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. original error packageAndLaunchActivityFrommanifest failed

Below picture describes more -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set you ANDROID HOME from edit configurations in APPIUM!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason may be you do not have "aapt" installed on your machine.
Execute "**sudo apt install aapt**" 
then restart your machine. 
I resolved my issue like this.. I hope it works for you too..